# Nexus 4 cracked screen touch no longer working and password locked (Android Device Manager)

Tags: nexus-4, touchscreen

Can anyone please provide some assistance. I managed to crack my screen yesterday and now can't enter the password to unlock. I tried using adb but get unauthorized error at prompt and can't approve device since i can't get into the device. Usb debugging is enabled on my nexus. Is there a backdoor available to remove/enter password?

Can I use a usb OTG mouse function for nexus 4?

I just want to get all text messages from my phone.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:** You might want to try [this unnamed Windows Tool](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2786395) created by **k.janku1**. You just need to have ADB enabled. The forum has additional info on enabling ADB via kernel or recovery. Once installed,

> this tool lets you use your device through your Windows pc even if
>   your touchscreen doesn't work or you can't see anything.

Direct download link [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5j0444hGlxeb0J3TDAtSmhKelU/edit?usp=sharing).

**Option 2:** A more complex solution would be to enable USB OTG support by providing you own 5v current and installing a custom kernel. The process is a bit involved and outlined in [this XDA forum](http://forum.xda-developers.com/nexus-4/general/manual-usb-otg-t2151159) discussion. A [video of a this working solution](https://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_embedded&v=Hs2M-m7j_a0) might also be beneficial to watch.